# Make a function accessible outside of a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Is there a way to make function created inside a closure accessible outside of the closure? I'm working with an AIR app and I need to provide access to the `specialFunction()` to AIR but the closure is keeping that from happening.

```
(function () {
    ... a bunch of code ..

    function specialFunction() {
        .. some code
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the function to the global object (which is `window` in browsers):

```
(function () {
    ... a bunch of code ..

    window.specialFuncton = function() {
        .. some code
    }
}());
```

This makes it globally available.

If the AIR application also needs access to other functions, then it is better to create a namespace for these functions:

```
var funcs = {}; // global

(function () {
    ... a bunch of code ..

    funcs.specialFuncton = function() {
        .. some code
    }
}());
```